# Touch screen application, C# Browser control crashing

Tags: c#, winforms, touch, webbrowser-control

I am using a Winforms WebBrowser control in my desktop application which is operated by a touch screen. When being operated via the touch sensors, the IE browser control crashes in random intervals. The application doesn't crash, it is only the IE Browser control. Has anyone ever had come across a problem with IE Browser control when used with touch screen desktop applications? Thanks

Comment: What crash looks like? Are there any logs, dumps?

Comment: Answering your "has anyone had come across this problem": I have recently implemented a WinForms application with WebBrowser control which is operated with touch sensors. I had no problems.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Ty

Comment: @Dennis, The only error it generates is this found on even log, Image link. [link](https://yadi.sk/i/Tv9NTlh3kZRkA)